# How to get a static version of my site?

Tags: php

I need to save a static version of my site by using the sitemap which has about 400 URLs.
What is the best way to do that?

Comment: There are lots of free web spider/crawler tools available out there.  Any one of them can take the sitemap page and follow all the links to make a static copy of all the contents of your site.

Comment: could you tell me some tools ?

Comment: I need to download ONLY URLs from the sitemaps.

Comment: from your responses it looks more like you want to create a sitemap? Or are you trying to grab urls as text from an existing sitemap file? its not clear... btw xml sitemaps free version will index up to 500 urls and create your sitemaps automatically http://www.xml-sitemaps.com/

Answer (score 3):

If you only want the URLs on your sitemap, then use the `-l depth` option in wget:

```
wget -r -l 1 http://your.domain.com/sitemap/
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `wget -r http://your_website_here.com/` to recursively download your website content.

Comment: I need to download only sitemap's URLs and not the entire site :)

Comment: but your question says: "How to get a static version of my site".  wget can pull only given urls: `wget -i sitemap`, it'll work if the sitemap file is an html page, or a plain list of urls.  But wouldn't that be downloading your entire site?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you don't want e.g. images etc. downloaded as well?

Either way, you could import the list of URLs (I believe importing a standard XML sitemap file will work as well) into e.g. A1 Website Download and do a little configuration like explained here:

http://www.microsystools.com/products/website-download/help/website-download-pages-list/

(Whatever download tool you end up deciding to use, you can always try email the vendor of the tool as well and ask for help specificly for the tool you use.)